# Listings in Minted not working

Tags: listings, minted

To surround the code with a box, the documentation suggested to use `listing` environment. But the code has no effect at all. What is the issue here:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}
\begin{document}
\begin{listing}[H]
\begin{minted}{java}
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a box, you don't need to wrap `minted` inside `listing`. A simple `frame=single` will do it. But `listing` wrapper is helpful in putting a caption (putting a `\label`) and producing a `list of listings`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{emacs}
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Program}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{List of Java codes}
\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\begin{listing}
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=olive!10]{java}  %% or frame=single
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
\end{minted}
\caption{My Java Code}\label{java:sample}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a frame add `frame=single` as in

```
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=olive!10,frame=single]{java}
```